# How do I pull down single cell RNA sequencing data from NCBI and process with python?

Tags: python, fastq, ncbi, rna-seq

I am new to scRNA sequencing analysis and having a hard time beginning the process of data analysis. I'm downloading the roughly 35GB dataset from NCBI using SRA ToolKit. (https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/index.html?view=run_browser&acc=SRR21002189&display=data-access).

Once I download it, I have it in the form of fastq. From here, I don't know what to do. The file is absolutely enormous, so the various scRNA sequencing tutorials online aren't great because the file size poses a completely different challenge.

I'm using Python.

Does anyone know what to do here? Or could you point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: So I figured out that I need to use FastQC to quality control and then I can align my reads with a reference transcriptome from Ensembl. I'm using Kallisto for that. Anyone have any thoughts on next steps or pit falls to look out for regarding FastQC, Kallisto, or anything else? Any advice or comments are greatly appreciated